# Using Sweave to include lattice graphics - issues with colour

Tags: color, sweave, eps

I am using Sweave and the R package nlme: when including lattice graphics, (encapsulated in the `print()` command), the `.eps` files that are generated are all in black and white. The original graphic, (which appears in R) and the saved `.pdf` file are in colour, but not the `.eps`.

When including graphics which do not use the lattice package, the `.eps` files are fine. I have tried including the lattice graphics in one step, e.g.:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]  
\begin{center}  
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\textwidth}  
<<echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE,width=4,height=4>>=
print(      plot(intervals(sulf1comp.lis),layout=c(3,1,1)#,main="Parameter Estimates     &   95% CI"  
        #,sub="Sulfadoxine: Bi-Exponential nlsList Model"  
        ))  
@ 
% 
\caption{Parameter Estimates and 95\% Confidence Intervals for Individual Model Fits       \label{label sulf_fig2}}  
 %\label{fig:}  
\end{center}  
\end{figure}
```

in two steps, explicitly:

```
<<figa,echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE,include=FALSE>>=  
 print(plot(sulf1comp.nls,pid~resid(.,type="p"),abline=0,cex.axis=0.7,  
 #,main="Plot of Residuals by Subject (Sulfadoxine: NLS Model)"  
        ))     
@ 
%    
\begin{figure}[!h]  
\begin{center}  
\includegraphics*[height=0.5\textwidth]{analysisinprogress_sw-figa.pdf}  
 \caption{Residuals by Subject ID: Sulfadoxine Bi-Exponential NLS Model \label{label       sulf_fig1}}  
 \end{center}  
\end{figure}
%
```

Without using the fig=T command, e.g.:

```
 <<figa,echo=FALSE>>=    
 postscript("filename.eps")    
print(plot(sulf1comp.nls,pid~resid(.,type="p"),abline=0,cex.axis=0.7,    
 #,main="Plot of Residuals by Subject (Sulfadoxine: NLS Model)"    
        ))      
 dev.off()     
 @    
 %
```

And various other possibilities. I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Black and white is the default for `eps`, whereas color is the default for `pdf` output.

I'm not sure setting

```
lattice.options(default.theme = standard.theme(color = TRUE))
```

would solve your problem, or equivalently (from the [Sweave FAQ](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/FAQ.html))

```
library(lattice)  
ltheme <- canonical.theme(color = TRUE)      ## in-built B&W theme  
ltheme$strip.background$col <- "transparent" ## change strip bg  
lattice.options(default.theme = ltheme)      ## set as default
```

but do you have any particular reason to prefer Postscript over PDF? I always found that the latter produce very nice looking graphics.